# Generic ServiceLocator GetInstance

Tags: c#, moq, service-locator

I am using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation assembly for creating ServiceLocator.

I am also mocking the ServiceLocator using

```
var mockS = new Mock<IServiceLocator>();
```

This mock should return the actual servicelocator so the code goes like

```
mockS.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<ISettings>()).Returns(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISettings>());
mockS.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<IContext>()).Returns(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContext>());
mockS.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<IXYZ>()).Returns(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IXYZ>());
```

I want to create a generic statement for this such as something like

```
mockS.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<It.IsAny<T>()>()).Returns(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>());
```

However i am not getting it to work. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a static instance, you need to set it first:

```
var mockS = new Mock<IServiceLocator>();
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => mockS.Object);
```

Then you can write setups on the mock instance:

```
mockS.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<ISettings>()).Returns(settingsMock);
```

You can't use `It.IsAny` method on type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need a generic method:

```
void SetupGetInstance<T>(Mock<IServiceLocator> mock) 
{
   mock.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<T>()).Returns(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>());   
}
```

And invoke it for each component in your IoC, for which you desire such setup. But, why do you mock it in the first place, if in all cases you just get an instance through `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>()`?

Comment: There are some cases where i want to return mock object and for rest all cases i want to get it through ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>()